# Tools for Romanization of Arabic

Tags: resource-request, arabic, transliteration

I would like a list of free and paid tools for [converting Arabic script into a Romanized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic), whether that is Franco-Arabic or some other form of Romanization/transliteration. Such tools are helpful with pronunciation.

Comment: Isn't that a bit subjective?

Comment: Is what subjective? That romanization helps with understanding Arabic words and how to pronounce them? No, it's a fact.

Comment: Claiming it is't subjective is nonsense! First romanization in the Maghreb states differs from that of the Mideast, and basically each Arabic speaker would use his own transliteration. As romanization or transliteration depends on how you pronounce the Latin letters a German speaker surely pronounces them differently than a French speaker and so on.

Comment: Whether شكرًا, for example, is transliterated as "shukran", "schukran", or "chukran" (the exact style could theoretically differ, as you said, depending on the background of the transliterator) is fairly irrelevant as long as the transliteration is consistent and makes sense. The style of transliteration could be considered subjective, you are correct, but the fact that romanization helps people learn how to pronounce Arabic words isn't subjective. Perhaps focus on trying to find an answer to the question instead of continuing to argue.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for this is Google Translate.

For example, with some random text from Wikipedia:

[image: Google Translate screenshot]

As you can see, it provides a Romanized representation of the text I input right below it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries mostly written in Python available on GitHub for free, you can find them here: https://github.com/search?q=arabic+transliterate

Additionally, if you perfer paid tools I would suggest taking a look at Wolfram Mathematica. It has a built-in function called [Transliterate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transliterate.html) that meets your requirement.